# How to binding ViewModel on DevExpression TreeListColumn?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I want to bind MyCustomers to TreeListControl  **TreeListColumn FieldName="Id"   Binding="How to bind CustomerId"** How can i do that?

```
<dxg:TreeListControl Name="MyControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCustomers}" 
     Height="296" Width="750" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Id"   Binding="How to Bind CustomerID ?????"    />
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CustomerGroup" Binding="How to Bind CustomerGroup ?????" />
    </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxg:TreeListView AutoWidth="True" KeyFieldName="Id" ParentFieldName="ParentId" NavigationStyle="Row" />
    </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
</dxg:TreeListControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IList<Model.App.Customer> MyCustomers
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        CustomerDetail = new CustomerDetail();
        this.MyCustomers = CustomerRespiratory.SelectMyCustomers();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Customer 
{
  public int CustomerID { get; set;}
  public int CustomerGroup { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?At first sight i say Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" could be what you need

Answer (score 1):

You should only specify CustomerID as Key Field and CustomerGroup as Parent Field. It is quite clearly described in ["Binding to Self-Referential Data Structure"](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9571) article:

```
<dxg:TreeListControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCustomers}">
    <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CustomerId"/>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CustomerGroup"/>
    </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxg:TreeListView KeyFieldName="CustomerId" ParentFieldName="CustomerGroup" 
                AutoWidth="True" NavigationStyle="Row" />
    </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
</dxg:TreeListControl>
```

You can read more in the ["TreeListView Data Binding"](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9701) article.

See also:
[DXTreeList Getting Started - Lesson 1 - Binding to Data](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9933)